# How to manage Tomcat 6 libraries into subfolders under %TOMCAT_HOME%/lib?

Tags: apache, tomcat, shared

I use Tomcat 6.0.20 and JDK 1.6.0.13.

How can I load libraries from sub-folders of `%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib/` without taking the .jars out of sub-folders and putting them straight into `%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib/`?

The reason I want to do this, is because many apps are going to be sharing lots of libraries.

So, for the sakes of organization I want to store them into folders as such:

```
%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib/novell/*.jar
%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib/mail/*.jar
%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib/upload/*.jar
```

etc.

How would I go about this? And please provide an example.
Do I use setclasspath.bat, catalina.properties or something completely different?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define those paths in `shared.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties` file.

E.g.

```
shared.loader = ${catalina.home}/lib/novell/*.jar, ${catalina.home}/lib/mail/*.jar, ${catalina.home}/lib/upload/*.jar
```

[Edit] optionally you can also use the `common.loader` property for this. See what has your preference.