# many identical websites on one server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jvm

I have a server (Linux/Apache-Tomcat & MySQL) which hosts several almost identical websites. At least, the java libraries are identical.

Right now, every website has it's own .jar file with these java classes.

I'd like to know if this is a good practice, or if I should have these classes in one place where each of the websites can access them? Would this improve performance in any way?  Would it result in less memory usage for the JVM? Are there any down-sides?

I haven't been able to find any information related to this situation.

Comment: I'm only asking if having only one .jar file instead of many identical .jar files is better. I don't think you would need many paragraphs to answer that (if you know the answer).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Third party libraries best practice in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397334/third-party-libraries-best-practice-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upsides: a small amount of disk space and RAM is saved. Remember that the only heap space taken belongs to the `java.lang.Class` instances representing the types you actually load from that JAR file.

Downsides: all applications in the JVM are locked-into using the version of the library that is shared. If you really want all deployed webapps to be identical, then this really is no downside. Deployments can get tricky because you have to maintain a non-standard deployment process (e.g. the webapp is not self-contained) that may be different from container-to-container or between versions of the same container (e.g. Tomcat changed its mind between versions 4 and 5, 5 and 5.5, and 5 and 6 for how to configure "common" and "shared" libraries).

If the web applications are identical, you should ask yourself: should you even be deploying more than one? Instead, you could sniff the URL and use a configuration for each kind of client instead of deploying the applications separately.